# GET on Twitter's /user/show/ returning Error:400 and Error:404 (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, twitter

Im making an `ajax` call that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url:"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id="+twitterId,
    contentType:"application/json",
    success:apiSuccessCallback,
    error:apiFailCallback
});
```

and im including `jsonp` as a workaround to cross-domain issues. However, I am getting the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

AND

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

If you're curious my `success` is a simple alert statement and my `error` is the same.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is the domain you're making the request from `https`?

Comment: I wasn't in https, but i tried https, and i got the same error

Comment: Is `apiFailCallback` being called?

Comment: no. It logs the errors in the console, and never makes it into the alert inside apiFailCallback

Answer (score 1):

I would try including the `suppress_response_codes` https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses

```
$.ajax({
   type:"GET",
   dataType: "jsonp",
  data: {
      suppress_response_codes: true
     },
   url:"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id="+twitterId,
   contentType:"application/json",
   success:apiSuccessCallback,
  error:apiFailCallback
});
```

From the documentation—

> If this parameter is present, all responses will be returned with a
>   200 OK status code - even errors. This parameter exists to accommodate
>   Flash and JavaScript applications running in browsers that intercept
>   all non-200 responses.

Comment: I don't think its an issue with the responses being suppressed...Is it because I need to authenticate this API call?

Comment: That's probably the issue, sorry, I assumed you authenticated.

Comment: You're correct...I am in the authentication process now...thanks anyways